# Не загружается Spring контекст

Tags: java, spring, context

Описал контекст следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.100.0.2:1521:t1"/>
    <property name="username" value=""/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

При запуске непосредственно из IDE, приложение работает корректно, но если собрать jar через maven, то валится с ошибкой:

```
WARNING: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 68; schema_reference
.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/
 spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could
 not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

С чем может быть связана данная проблема?

**UPDATE**.
`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>estaff_sync</groupId>
<artifactId>estaff</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>

                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>artifactory</id>
        <url>http://10.100.0.137:8081/artifactory/remote-repos/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: а когда вы собираете jar, вы включаете туда этот XML? покажите pom файл, пожалуйста

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, pom показал. В него не включил, подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, добавил это: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">, ошибка сохранилась. Может надо в pom что то добавить, чтобы он их тоже упаковал в jar?

Comment: нет. у вас описание хромает. возьмите все описание отсюда https://ideone.com/WOjL4T . пробуйте и скажите что за ошибка

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, мне не видны ссылки: http://w...content-available-to-author-only...k.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://w...content-available-to-author-only...3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://w...content-available-to-author-only...k.org/schema/util

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, опять тоже самое  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                   + "<beans xmlns=\"http://w...content-available-to-author-only...k.org/schema/beans\"\n"
                   + "       xmlns:xsi=\"http://w...content-available-to-author-only...3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:util=\"http://w...content-available-to-author-only...k.org/schema/util\"\n"

Comment: да чтож такое. вот https://github.com/Tsovak/vSphereWebSDK/blob/master/src/main/resources/spring.xml

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, вставил ваше описание. Ошибка такая: WARNING: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 124; schema_referenc
e.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document coul
d not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.

Comment: я понял! 

ты в `spring.xml`  закрываешь тэг бинов `</beans>`?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, да, тэг закрываю: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
</beans>

Comment: @S.Ivanov 6 строка это бин `dataSource`, правильно я понимаю? Попробуйте удалить из этого бина строку ` destroy-method="close"`. Ну или удалите весь бин dataSource в этом файле и пропишите в другом.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, это не помогло

Comment: @S.Ivanov покажите весь spring.xml и код, который вызываете с новыми изменениями и трейсом ошибки